# How does enumerators created with code block actually runs

Tags: ruby, enumerator

It's just a simple question, how is `y.<<` method is able to halt the code-block mid execution ??

I have expected the code block to run only once and never halt in the middle :/

```
e = Enumerator.new do |y|
    puts "Ruby"
    y << 1
    y << 2
    puts "Ruby"
    y << 3
end

puts e.each.next
puts e.each.next
puts e.each.next
e.rewind
puts e.each.next
puts e.each.next
puts e.each.next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all Ruby implementations are Free Software and Open Source, so you can just look at the source code to see how it is implemented.

In [Rubinius](https://rubinius.com/), the most interesting part is `Enumerator::Iterator#reset`, implemented in [`core/enumerator.rb`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/enumerator.rb#L491-L498):

```ruby
@fiber = Fiber.new stack_size: STACK_SIZE do
  obj = @object
  @result = obj.each { |*val| Fiber.yield *val }
  @done = true
end
```

and [`Enumerator::Iterator#next`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/enumerator.rb#L476-L484):

```ruby
val = @fiber.resume
```

[TruffleRuby](https://graalvm.org/ruby/)'s implementation is very similar, as you can see in [`src/main/ruby/truffleruby/core/enumerator.rb`](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/blob/master/src/main/ruby/truffleruby/core/enumerator.rb#L601-L639):

```ruby
class FiberGenerator
  # irrelevant methods omitted

  def next
    reset unless @fiber

    val = @fiber.resume

    raise StopIteration, 'iteration has ended' if @done

    val
  end

  def reset
    @done = false
    @fiber = Fiber.new do
      obj = @object
      @result = obj.each do |*val|
        Fiber.yield(*val)
      end
      @done = true
    end
  end
end
```

[JRuby](https://www.jruby.org/) is also very similar, as you can see in [`core/src/main/ruby/jruby/kernel/enumerator.rb`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/ruby/jruby/kernel/enumerator.rb#L65-L122):

```ruby
class FiberGenerator
  # irrelevant methods omitted

  def next
    reset unless @fiber&.__alive__

    val = @fiber.resume

    raise StopIteration, 'iteration has ended' if @state.done

    val
  end

  def reset
    @state.done = false
    @state.result = nil
    @fiber = Fiber.new(&@state)
  end

end
```

[MRuby](https://mruby.org/)'s implementation is very similar, as you can see in [`mrbgems/mruby-enumerator/mrblib/enumerator.rb`](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/master/mrbgems/mruby-enumerator/mrblib/enumerator.rb#L363-L401).

[YARV](https://atdot.net/yarv/) also uses Fibers, as can be seen in [`enumerator.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/enumerator.c#L725-L784), for example here:

```c
static void
next_init(VALUE obj, struct enumerator *e)
{
    VALUE curr = rb_fiber_current();
    e->dst = curr;
    e->fib = rb_fiber_new(next_i, obj);
    e->lookahead = Qundef;
}

static VALUE
get_next_values(VALUE obj, struct enumerator *e)
{
    VALUE curr, vs;

    if (e->stop_exc)
    rb_exc_raise(e->stop_exc);

    curr = rb_fiber_current();

    if (!e->fib || !rb_fiber_alive_p(e->fib)) {
    next_init(obj, e);
    }

    vs = rb_fiber_resume(e->fib, 1, &curr);
    if (e->stop_exc) {
    e->fib = 0;
    e->dst = Qnil;
    e->lookahead = Qundef;
    e->feedvalue = Qundef;
    rb_exc_raise(e->stop_exc);
    }
    return vs;
}
```

So, not surprisingly, [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html) is implemented using [`Fiber`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Fiber.html)s in many Ruby implementations. `Fiber` is essentially just Ruby's name for [*semi-coroutines*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine#Generators), and of course, coroutines are a popular way of implementing [generators](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)) and [iterators](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#Generators). E.g. CPython and CoreCLR also implement generators using coroutines.

One exception to this seems to be [Opal](https://opalrb.com/). My assumption was that Opal would use [ECMAScript *Generators*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-generator-objects) to implement Ruby `Enumerator`s, but it does not look like that is the case. The implementation of Ruby `Enumerator`s in Opal is found in [`opal/corelib/enumerator.rb`](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/enumerator.rb), [`opal/corelib/enumerator/generator.rb`](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/enumerator/generator.rb), and [`opal/corelib/enumerator/yielder.rb`](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/enumerator/yielder.rb) with some help from [`opal/corelib/runtime.js`](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/runtime.js), but unfortunately, I don't fully understand it. It does not appear to use either Ruby `Fiber`s or ECMAScript *Generators*, though.

By the way, your usage of `Enumerator`s is somewhat strange: you call [`Enumerator#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) six times without a block, but calling `Enumerator#each` without a block just returns the `Enumerator` itself:

> ## `each` → `enum`
>
> Iterates over the block according to how this `Enumerator` was constructed. If no block and no arguments are given, returns self.

So, in other words, all those calls to `Enumerator#each` are just no-ops. It would make much more sense to just call [`Enumerator#next`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) directly:

```ruby
puts e.next
puts e.next
puts e.next
e.rewind
puts e.next
puts e.next
puts e.next
```